# Spark AR: sending a vector from script

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I want to send a vector value from script to the editor (in order to change the spray angle of an emitter).
What is wrong with the line

`Patches.setVectorValue('sprayAngle', Reactive.pack3(0, 0, 0));`  ?

It marks an unknown runtime error at the first parenthesis.
I suppose, there actually needs to be a `Vector` as the second argument (and not `VectorSignal`), but how do I create a custom vector? There is afaik nothing like `new Vector()` in Spark AR.
Sending boolean and scalar values is no problem though, the problem is just with sending Vector or Point. I am somewhat confused with these signals/non-signals, Vectors/Points.

Comment: I think it's `Reactive.vector(0, 0, 0)` - docs here https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/reactivemodule - actually, no. Docs say it needs to be a `VectorSignal`, which is `Reactive.VectorSignal(0, 0, 0)` - docs here https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/patchesmodule

Comment: That's it! `Reactive.vector(0, 0, 0)`. Thanks! (`VectorSignal` doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Sergiu Paraschiv already mentioned in the comments, it needs to be

```
Patches.setVectorValue('sprayAngle', Reactive.vector(0, 0, 0));
```